# Remove items in setting pane in metro app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm developing metro app using C# and XAML, In my App i have two views View1 and View2, For View1 i need to have a setting pane with "Options,About,Logout" as setting options,
For View2 i need to remove those settings, So how do i remove settings options from setting charm,
If any one know about this Please help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: Think about hiding the options and not deleting. It. When View2 is selected. then hide thse options with option.Visibility=Visiblity.Collapsed

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [MSDN App settings sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-settings-sample-1f762f49). Basically, what you need to do is:

1. Hook up the CommandsRequested event handler: `SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += onCommandsRequested;`
2. In your event handler `onCommandsRequested`, decide whether to add or remove the `SettingsCommand`s based on which View your app is presenting.

   ```
   if (View1)
   {
       if (commands not added)
       {
           // add commands
       }
   }
   else if (View2)
   {
       if (commands not removed)
       {
           // removed commands
       }
   }
   else
   {
       throw new Exception("Unknown view!");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
void OnCommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Clear();
    // or
    args.Request.ApplicationCommands.RemoveAt(0);
}
```